# Filtering parent table by data in child table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

There are 2 tables to track baseball players and their positions..

Player

```
+----+----------
| id | name    
+----+----------
|  1 | Boggs    
|  2 | Mattingly
|  3 | Judge
|  4 | Martinez
|  5 | Rodriguez
```

Position

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | player_id |   position   
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | 1        | Pitcher   
|  2 | 1        | Third Base    
|  3 | 2        | First Base  
|  4 | 3        | Second Base    
|  5 | 3        | Pitcher
```

So Boggs is a pitcher and plays third base, while Mattingly only plays first page and Judge is a pithcer and second baseman.

Is there a way in MySQL to get only the players which are not pitchers? So the result from this sample should be Mattingly only.

Of course I can't do....

```
select id from Player where id not in (select player_id from Position where position = 'Pitcher')
```

because this will return Mattingly, Boggs and Judge.

Comment: you forgot the `where position='Pitcher'` in the subquery (assuming you want all the player that are not pitchers, including the ones without a position at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select p.* from player p
join position pn on p.id = pn.player_id
where pn.position not in ('Pitcher')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
select id from Player where id not in 
    (select player_id from Position WHERE position = 'Pitcher')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the name of your table from `'Position'` to `'Positions'` because it shouldn't have the same name as your column name. Once that's done, you should be able to use the query in the above answer.

```
select id from Player where id not in 
(select player_id from Position WHERE position = 'Pitcher')
```